# Книга про технологии разработки ПО, управлению проектами, IT-стратегии на предприятии

Tags: книги

Помогите выбрать книжку по одной из перечисленных областей, только чтобы можно было её скачать в электронном варианте, а то куда не кинь, везде ссылки на Озон и т.п.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Гради Буч - Object-Oriented Analysis and Design with Applications.
- Г. Маерс - Надежность Программного Обеспечения.
- Орлов - Технология Разработки Программного Обеспечения.
- Якобсон - Унифицированный процесс разработки программного обеспечения.

Answer (score 2):

Технологии разработки программного обеспечения. Эрих Брадуе.

Answer (score 0):

моя любимая книга,которую перечитал больше 10 раз,это "Deadline. Роман об управлении проектами" Тома ДеМарко. Книга которая читается взахлеб,и будет получше многих художественных книг и самое главное,там есть ценная инфа!
пс. странно,что её ни кто не предложил

Answer (score 0):

Ф. Брукс - Мифический человеко-месяц.